# Android things: 1.0.0 Issue: Superclass com.google.android.things.pio.GpioCallback of com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button

Tags: java, driver, android-things

*I have this code in github*

https://github.com/neuberfran/sample-button-master

***I have a issue:***  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:Superclass com.google.android.things.pio.GpioCallback of com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button.Button$InterruptCallback is an interface (declaration of 'com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button.Button$InterruptCallback' appears in /data/app/com.example.androidthings.button-,

as quoted in the topic, and stay on the ***line 72 below*** (***I think***)

```
BoardDefaults.getGPIOForButton(),
            Button.LogicState.PRESSED_WHEN_HIGH,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
    mButtonInputDriver.register();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error configuring GPIO pins", e);
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_HEbFc-2sxk9QXPBzTnsrScTNfomC5E/view?usp=sharing

***e.g.: OS version 1.0.0***
***Date:*** May 2018
***Build Number:*** OIM1.180327.036
***Play Services:*** 12.5.20

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Button driver for Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/button) description:

> **Gradle dependency**
>
> To use the button driver, simply add the line below to your project's
>   build.gradle, where  matches the last version of the driver
>   available on [jcenter](https://bintray.com/google/androidthings/contrib-driver-button/_latestVersion).
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-button:<version>'
> }
> ```

Now latest version is 1.0, so in your [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/neuberfran/sample-button-master/blob/master/app/build.gradle) file in `dependencies` section remove line

`compile'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-button:0.3'`

(line #42) and update in line #45 driver-button version to 1.0:

`implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-button:1.0'`.

Than, update `compileSdkVersion` (line 20) `minSdkVersion` (line 27) and `targetSdkVersion` (line 29) to 27 (instead of 24 and 25) and resync project.